# Looking for a word that means, "You have completed the work to my satisfaction"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am building a customer request web site for our organization. When a user submits a request (for example, to get a new mobile phone), and that request is completed, the site sends them an email saying, "Click here to confirm that your request has been completed to your satisfaction".

So, when they follow the link, they see their request. I want to have a nice, big button they click that means "Yes, you have satisfied my request." I am trying to find ONE WORD to put on that button that is intiutive and obvious to any user. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with **OK**, which [has been described as the world's most widely understood word?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK)

Comment: OK is already on use on the form to confirm an edit. I want a different word that can't be confused with anything else, such as "Validate" or "Approve" which are already used within the site.

Comment: Is "to your satisfaction" important?  Why not "confirm that your request has been completed"?

Comment: Well, I think your question is Off Topic for ELU anyway, but you might get some help on [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). I suspect they might tell you the first thing to do is get rid of your existing and potentially confusing "OK" button, but I'm no expert.

Comment: Use [smileys](http://www.clipartkid.com/images/267/31-happy-and-sad-faces-images-free-cliparts-that-you-can-download-to-Z5toYT-clipart.jpeg).

Comment: Since your instructions say, “click here to confirm...” the button ought to say “Confirm”

Answer (score 3):

Most UI/UX designers would say that the affirmative verb on a button should match the one in the accompanying message.

E.g. the [Windows guidelines say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738363.aspx):

> - Use buttons with text that identifies specific responses to the main instruction or content. An example is, "Do you want to allow AppName to access your location?", followed by "Allow" and "Block" buttons. Specific responses can be understood more quickly, resulting in efficient decision making.
> - Avoid using generic patterns such as "OK/Cancel".

and the [Mac guidelines say](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/WindowAlerts.html):

> **Ensure that the default button name corresponds to the action you describe**. In particular, it’s a good idea to avoid using OK for the default button. The meaning of OK can be unclear even in alerts that ask if users are sure they want to do something. For example, does OK mean “OK, I want to complete the action” or “OK, I now understand the negative results my action would have caused”?
>
> Using a more focused button name, such as Erase, Convert, Clear, or Delete, helps make sure that users understand the action they’re taking.

So if the customer has just read a message that says "Click here to confirm [something]", then I would certainly consider having the button label be "Confirm".

(Background: I've been a UI designer for the past 20+ years.)

Answer (score 0):

Since they are confirming, how about "confirmed"?

Comment: Rather "confirm"

Comment: As it stands, you answer reads like a comment. Please include references to support your answer.